# Concurrent modification issue with Node children list

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have an issue that probably has it's cause in the concurrent modification of a list, and I want to understand what exactly is happening in this case:

```
List<Node> childrenUnmodifiable = shipCanvas.getChildrenUnmodifiable();
for (Node node : childrenUnmodifiable) {
    ...
```

The `shipCanvas` is of type `javafx.scene.layout.Pane`.
In the above case it may occur that I get a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` on the line of the for loop. Is my assumption correct that his happens because when creating the `childrenUnmodifiable` list the list was altered?
When I employ a defensive copy strategy:

```
List<Node> childrenUnmodifiable = new ArrayList<>(shipCanvas.getChildren());
for (Node node : childrenUnmodifiable) {
    ...
```

I get a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` when creating the `childrenUnmodifiable`. 
What options are there to avoid this behaviour? It would be acceptable to retrieve an element from the list that is  actually no longer in there.
I can see two options:

1. Lock all access to the children of `shipCanvas`.
2. Execute everything in a single thread.

I am not happy with both options especially the second one, as that single thread would have to be the UI thread. So are there any other options I am missing?

Comment: `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs when you try to add/remove elements from a list while you are iterating over it. The exception should be occurring inside your for loop, but I couldn't say for sure without the stack trace or the code inside the loop.

Comment: Assuming `shipCanvas` is part of the scene graph, you should only access it (and its child nodes) from the FX Application Thread anyway. (But as stated, a `ConcurrentModificationException` is not necessarily caused by multithreading at all.)